# How to determine the longest increasing subsequence using dynamic programming?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, dynamic-programming, memoization, lis

I have a set of integers. I want to find the [longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) of that set using dynamic programming.

Comment: Speaking about DP solution, I found it surprising that no one mentioned the fact that [LIS can be reduced to LCS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36836767/1090562).

Comment: very nicely explained [LIS](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-increasing-subsequence/discuss/1326308/C%2B%2BPython-DP-Binary-Search-BIT-Solutions-Picture-explain-O(NlogN))

Answer (score 438, accepted):

OK, I will describe first the simplest solution which is O(N^2), where N is the size of the collection. There also exists a O(N log N) solution, which I will describe also. Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) for it at the section Efficient algorithms.

I will assume the indices of the array are from 0 to N - 1. So let's define `DP[i]` to be the length of the LIS (Longest increasing subsequence) which is ending at element with index `i`. To compute `DP[i]` we look at all indices `j < i` and check both if `DP[j] + 1 > DP[i]` and `array[j] < array[i]` (we want it to be increasing). If this is true we can update the current optimum for `DP[i]`. To find the global optimum for the array you can take the maximum value from `DP[0...N - 1]`.

```
int maxLength = 1, bestEnd = 0;
DP[0] = 1;
prev[0] = -1;

for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
{
   DP[i] = 1;
   prev[i] = -1;

   for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
      if (DP[j] + 1 > DP[i] && array[j] < array[i])
      {
         DP[i] = DP[j] + 1;
         prev[i] = j;
      }

   if (DP[i] > maxLength)
   {
      bestEnd = i;
      maxLength = DP[i];
   }
}
```

I use the array `prev` to be able later to find the actual sequence not only its length. Just go back recursively from `bestEnd` in a loop using `prev[bestEnd]`. The `-1` value is a sign to stop.

---

### OK, now to the more efficient `O(N log N)` solution:

Let `S[pos]` be defined as the smallest integer that ends an increasing sequence of length `pos`. Now iterate through every integer `X` of the input set and do the following:

1. If `X` > last element in `S`, then append `X` to the end of `S`. This essentially means we have found a new largest `LIS`.
2. Otherwise find the smallest element in `S`, which is `>=` than `X`, and change it to `X`.
   Because `S` is sorted at any time, the element can be found using binary search in `log(N)`.

Total runtime - `N` integers and a binary search for each of them - N * log(N) = O(N log N)

Now let's do a real example:

Collection of integers:
`2 6 3 4 1 2 9 5 8`

Steps:

```
0. S = {} - Initialize S to the empty set
1. S = {2} - New largest LIS
2. S = {2, 6} - New largest LIS
3. S = {2, 3} - Changed 6 to 3
4. S = {2, 3, 4} - New largest LIS
5. S = {1, 3, 4} - Changed 2 to 1
6. S = {1, 2, 4} - Changed 3 to 2
7. S = {1, 2, 4, 9} - New largest LIS
8. S = {1, 2, 4, 5} - Changed 9 to 5
9. S = {1, 2, 4, 5, 8} - New largest LIS
```

So the length of the LIS is `5` (the size of S).

To reconstruct the actual `LIS` we will again use a parent array.
Let `parent[i]` be the predecessor of an element with index `i` in the `LIS` ending at the element with index `i`.

To make things simpler, we can keep in the array `S`, not the actual integers, but their indices(positions) in the set. We do not keep `{1, 2, 4, 5, 8}`, but keep `{4, 5, 3, 7, 8}`.

That is input[4] = **1**, input[5] = **2**, input[3] = **4**, input[7] = **5**, input[8] = **8**.

If we update properly the parent array, the actual LIS is:

```
input[S[lastElementOfS]], 
input[parent[S[lastElementOfS]]],
input[parent[parent[S[lastElementOfS]]]],
........................................
```

Now to the important thing - how do we update the parent array? There are two options:

1. If `X` > last element in `S`, then `parent[indexX] = indexLastElement`. This means the parent of the newest element is the last element. We just prepend `X` to the end of `S`.
2. Otherwise find the index of the smallest element in `S`, which is `>=` than `X`, and change it to `X`. Here `parent[indexX] = S[index - 1]`.

Comment: The condition should be `if (DP[j] + 1 >= DP[i] && array[j] < array[i])` instead of `if (DP[j] + 1 > DP[i] && array[j] < array[i])`, don't you think so?

Comment: It doesn't matter. If `DP[j] + 1 == DP[i]` then `DP[i]` won't become better with `DP[i] = DP[j] + 1`. We are trying to optimize `DP[i]`.

Comment: Can you explain the `O(N log N)` solution given at the link you mentioned? I cannot understand it..

Comment: But here the answer should be `[1,2,5,8]`, 4 comes before 1 in the array, how can the LIS be `[1,2,4,5,8]`?

Comment: @Cupidvogel - The answer is `[2,3,4,5,8]`. Read carefully - the `S` array `DOES NOT` represent an actual sequence. `Let S[pos] be defined as the smallest integer that ends an increasing sequence of length pos.`

Comment: So now the length of `S` is 5, so I know that the length of the LIS is 5. But how do I construct the actual LIS from it, like you did in your original solution?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19925/discussion-between-petar-minchev-and-cupidvogel)

Comment: I have updated my post. If you have any questions go to chat, by clicking `continue this discussion in chat`.

Comment: @PetarMinchev Nice explanation +1. Just have one doubt, can't i make this `DP[j] + 1 > DP[i]` to `DP[j] >= DP[i]`? Thanks.

Comment: By the way, this algorithm is due to Craige Schensted.

Comment: It seems to that the first algorithm finds the longest increasing subsequence, and the second one finds the longest increasing subset.

Comment: Both algorithms find the longest increasing subsequence. What made you think the second algorithm is different?

Comment: Position of array elements are not taken into account for "sequencing". @PetarMinchev

Comment: Positions are taken into account. Please read the algorithm description at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence, in the section "Efficient algorithms".

Comment: @Kraken - Yes, using the `prev` array you will find only one subsequence. To find all subsequences you don't need the `prev` array. When restoring and you are at index `cur`, then you have to examine all previous indices `i` < `cur`, such that `DP[i] = DP[cur] - 1` and `array[i] < array[cur]`. You can use recursion to print all.

Comment: @PetarMinchev That will be using the first approach right? What about the second one? How do I do the entire process in nlogn?

Comment: @Kraken - Well you can also do the same for the second approach. To restore all sequences, you don't need the `parent` array. Just create another array `DP`, which will hold the length of `LIS` for each position in the array. When length of `S` is extended with one more element, then `DP[i] = length(S)`. This was case `1`. For case 2 -  `DP[i] = positionOfSmallestElementFoundWithBinarySearch`. After having `DP`, then you can do the same as in my previous comment.

Comment: But doing effectively the process described in my previous comment is another story - `then you have to examine all previous indices i < cur, such that DP[i] = DP[cur] - 1 and array[i] < array[cur]`.

Comment: I don't often see such clear explanations. Not only it's very easy to understand, because the doubts are cleared within the explanation, but also it addresses any implementation problem that might arise. Awesome.

Comment: +1 the step-by-step example. But :
1. (major) At first reading, I considered that every step in your example produces an increasing subsequence, the last step giving the requested subsequence. Indeed your comments give to understand that way (eg "New largest LIS"). Of course, this is not the case but it is easy to be confused : each step gives an increasing sequence of elements of the initial array T but NOT a SUBsequence of T;
2. (minor) a set data-structure has no natural order end no right side. However, you define the sequence to be built as a "set", eg "Initialize S to the empty set"

Comment: @PetarMinchev Hi Petar, I am solving a problem of finding ALL LIS. I used second method of O(nlogn) complexity. But if I print all solution using recursion on DP structure, won't it become slower? Is there any optimized way to print all LIS?

Comment: @PetarMinchev I've having some trouble understanding the parents array. Can you list how how the parent array is updated on each iteration?

Comment: How does your example work? Your second algorithm with the input `{2 6 3 4 1 2 9 5 8}` has a LIS of `{2 3 4 5 8 }` and NOT `{1, 2, 4, 5, 8} `. Can you explain whats happening there?

Comment: S is not containing the LIS. Read again "Let S[pos] be defined as the smallest integer that could possibly end an increasing sequence of length pos". To reconstruct the LIS you need the parent array.

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-monotonically-increasing-subsequence-size-n-log-n/ is probably the best explanation of this i've seen

Comment: @PetarMinchev Amazing explanation. Much better than geeksforgeeks.org and Wikipedia itself. Thank you so much for explaining it this brief and clearly.

Comment: i could not understand 1) why do we have `DP[j] + 1 > DP[i]` this condition ? 2) how do we know that the `array[j] < array[i]` is  going to verify that there are no numbers greater than `array[j]` before `j` ?

Comment: 1) The condition is to make sure a smaller sequence doesn't overwrite a sequence of greater length. If `DP[i] = 4`, and `DP[j] + 1 = 2`, we don't want `DP[i]` to become `2` and to be overwritten with a smaller length.

Comment: 2) You seem to be confused here. There can be numbers greater than `array[j]` before `j` and that is ok. The important thing is that we know that `DP[j]` is containing the length of a sequence of only strictly increasing numbers.

Comment: @Peter thanks for your explanation. I'm still struggling on how to construct the LIS array having constructed `S`. Updating the `parent` array doesn't seem to make sense. Do you do this in the same loop that you are finding `S` in?

Comment: Yes, immediately after changing something in `S`, you change the `parent` too. `S` is containing indices. `S[pos]` = the index of the smallest integer possible, which is the last number of a `LIS` of length `pos`. There are only two cases when updating `S` and for each case you update parent accordingly. The two cases are described at the end - prepending to end of `S`, or updating `S` somewhere in the inside of it.

Comment: @PetarMinchev Hi, can you please explain how to find the actual LIS using the O(N log N) algorithm?

Comment: also, how can `S[lastElementOfS]` exist, if S[8] doesn't exist?

Comment: You said this, about updating the parent array - `We just prepend X to the end of S.` Isn't that changing `S`, not the parent array?

Comment: I'm having a very hard time understanding why all definitions for "DP[i]" are "the length of the LIS(Longest increasing subsequence) which is ending at element with index i".  Why do we define it as such? Couldn't we define DP[i] to be the length of the longest increasing sequence that's present in the array up to index i?

Comment: @Greener: because if you define DP[i] as length of LIS, then that doesn't help you build a substructure you can use to derive the higher answer order. Then, with the next value at index i+1, how do you know if it increases the LIS at any point in DP[0..i]. it just becomes like a greedy polynomial time solution.

Comment: I'm having a somewhat hard time parsing this: "Let parent[i] be the predecessor of element with index i in the LIS ending at element with index i." - is it Let parent[i] be the predecessor of *element with index i in the LIS ending at element with index i* or Let parent[i] be the *predecessor of element with index i in the LIS* ending at element with index i.

Comment: Another explanation that will top GeekgForGeeks blog :D http://lightoj.com/article_show.php?article=1000&language=english&type=pdf

Comment: the best explanation i've seen: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22s1xxRvy28

Answer (score 64):

Petar Minchev's explanation helped clear things up for me, but it was hard for me to parse what everything was, so I made a Python implementation with overly-descriptive variable names and lots of comments.  I did a naive recursive solution, the O(n^2) solution, and the O(n log n) solution.

I hope it helps clear up the algorithms!

## The Recursive Solution

```py
def recursive_solution(remaining_sequence, bigger_than=None):
    """Finds the longest increasing subsequence of remaining_sequence that is      
    bigger than bigger_than and returns it.  This solution is O(2^n)."""

    # Base case: nothing is remaining.                                             
    if len(remaining_sequence) == 0:
        return remaining_sequence

    # Recursive case 1: exclude the current element and process the remaining.     
    best_sequence = recursive_solution(remaining_sequence[1:], bigger_than)

    # Recursive case 2: include the current element if it's big enough.            
    first = remaining_sequence[0]

    if (first > bigger_than) or (bigger_than is None):

        sequence_with = [first] + recursive_solution(remaining_sequence[1:], first)

        # Choose whichever of case 1 and case 2 were longer.                         
        if len(sequence_with) >= len(best_sequence):
            best_sequence = sequence_with

    return best_sequence
```

## The O(n^2) Dynamic Programming Solution

```py
def dynamic_programming_solution(sequence):
    """Finds the longest increasing subsequence in sequence using dynamic          
    programming.  This solution is O(n^2)."""

    longest_subsequence_ending_with = []
    backreference_for_subsequence_ending_with = []
    current_best_end = 0

    for curr_elem in range(len(sequence)):
        # It's always possible to have a subsequence of length 1.                    
        longest_subsequence_ending_with.append(1)

        # If a subsequence is length 1, it doesn't have a backreference.             
        backreference_for_subsequence_ending_with.append(None)

        for prev_elem in range(curr_elem):
            subsequence_length_through_prev = (longest_subsequence_ending_with[prev_elem] + 1)

            # If the prev_elem is smaller than the current elem (so it's increasing)   
            # And if the longest subsequence from prev_elem would yield a better       
            # subsequence for curr_elem.                                               
            if ((sequence[prev_elem] < sequence[curr_elem]) and
                    (subsequence_length_through_prev >
                         longest_subsequence_ending_with[curr_elem])):

                # Set the candidate best subsequence at curr_elem to go through prev.    
                longest_subsequence_ending_with[curr_elem] = (subsequence_length_through_prev)
                backreference_for_subsequence_ending_with[curr_elem] = prev_elem
                # If the new end is the best, update the best.    

        if (longest_subsequence_ending_with[curr_elem] >
                longest_subsequence_ending_with[current_best_end]):
            current_best_end = curr_elem
            # Output the overall best by following the backreferences.  

    best_subsequence = []
    current_backreference = current_best_end

    while current_backreference is not None:
        best_subsequence.append(sequence[current_backreference])
        current_backreference = (backreference_for_subsequence_ending_with[current_backreference])

    best_subsequence.reverse()

    return best_subsequence
```

## The O(n log n) Dynamic Programming Solution

```py
def find_smallest_elem_as_big_as(sequence, subsequence, elem):
    """Returns the index of the smallest element in subsequence as big as          
    sequence[elem].  sequence[elem] must not be larger than every element in       
    subsequence.  The elements in subsequence are indices in sequence.  Uses       
    binary search."""

    low = 0
    high = len(subsequence) - 1

    while high > low:
        mid = (high + low) / 2
        # If the current element is not as big as elem, throw out the low half of    
        # sequence.                                                                  
        if sequence[subsequence[mid]] < sequence[elem]:
            low = mid + 1
            # If the current element is as big as elem, throw out everything bigger, but 
        # keep the current element.                                                  
        else:
            high = mid

    return high


def optimized_dynamic_programming_solution(sequence):
    """Finds the longest increasing subsequence in sequence using dynamic          
    programming and binary search (per                                             
    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence).  This solution   
    is O(n log n)."""

    # Both of these lists hold the indices of elements in sequence and not the        
    # elements themselves.                                                         
    # This list will always be sorted.                                             
    smallest_end_to_subsequence_of_length = []

    # This array goes along with sequence (not                                     
    # smallest_end_to_subsequence_of_length).  Following the corresponding element 
    # in this array repeatedly will generate the desired subsequence.              
    parent = [None for _ in sequence]

    for elem in range(len(sequence)):
        # We're iterating through sequence in order, so if elem is bigger than the   
        # end of longest current subsequence, we have a new longest increasing          
        # subsequence.                                                               
        if (len(smallest_end_to_subsequence_of_length) == 0 or
                    sequence[elem] > sequence[smallest_end_to_subsequence_of_length[-1]]):
            # If we are adding the first element, it has no parent.  Otherwise, we        
            # need to update the parent to be the previous biggest element.            
            if len(smallest_end_to_subsequence_of_length) > 0:
                parent[elem] = smallest_end_to_subsequence_of_length[-1]
            smallest_end_to_subsequence_of_length.append(elem)
        else:
            # If we can't make a longer subsequence, we might be able to make a        
            # subsequence of equal size to one of our earlier subsequences with a         
            # smaller ending number (which makes it easier to find a later number that 
            # is increasing).                                                          
            # Thus, we look for the smallest element in                                
            # smallest_end_to_subsequence_of_length that is at least as big as elem       
            # and replace it with elem.                                                
            # This preserves correctness because if there is a subsequence of length n 
            # that ends with a number smaller than elem, we could add elem on to the   
            # end of that subsequence to get a subsequence of length n+1.              
            location_to_replace = find_smallest_elem_as_big_as(sequence, smallest_end_to_subsequence_of_length, elem)
            smallest_end_to_subsequence_of_length[location_to_replace] = elem
            # If we're replacing the first element, we don't need to update its parent 
            # because a subsequence of length 1 has no parent.  Otherwise, its parent  
            # is the subsequence one shorter, which we just added onto.                
            if location_to_replace != 0:
                parent[elem] = (smallest_end_to_subsequence_of_length[location_to_replace - 1])

    # Generate the longest increasing subsequence by backtracking through parent.  
    curr_parent = smallest_end_to_subsequence_of_length[-1]
    longest_increasing_subsequence = []

    while curr_parent is not None:
        longest_increasing_subsequence.append(sequence[curr_parent])
        curr_parent = parent[curr_parent]

    longest_increasing_subsequence.reverse()

    return longest_increasing_subsequence
```

Comment: Your optimized algorithm is incorrect. Please test the case when sequence is 5, 19, 5, 81, 50, 28, 29, 1, 83, 23. Your algorithm returns 5, 19, 81, 83 when it should return 5, 19, 28, 29, 83.

Comment: Are you sure?  When I run optimized_dynamic_programming_solution([5, 19, 5, 81, 50, 28, 29, 1, 83, 23]) on my computer, it returns [5, 19, 28, 29, 83].

Comment: Although I appreciate the effort here, my eyes hurt when I stare at those pseudo-codes.

Comment: mostruash -- I'm not sure what you mean.  My answer doesn't have pseudo code; it has Python.

Comment: Well he most probably means your naming convention of variables and functions,which also made my eyes 'hurt'

Comment: If you mean my naming convention, I'm mostly following the Google Python Style Guide.  If you are advocating short variable names, I prefer descriptive variable names because they make code easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: cool. but don't you think using `bisect` instead of `find_smallest_elem_as_big_as` would clear it up?

Comment: For an actual implementation, it would probably make sense to use `bisect`.    For a demonstration of how an algorithm works and its performance characteristics, I was trying to keep things as primitive as possible.

Comment: @SamKing where did you get your recursive solution from?

Comment: [edit: nvm I think I found it] http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/notes/03-backtracking.pdf

Comment: This is a very useful solution, but I need to note that I took `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float` error in dynamic solution code because of the line  `mid = (high + low) / 2`. I guess, it should be `mid = (high + low) // 2` or `mid = int((high + low) / 2)`

Comment: All of the code is working python2 code.  If you're running it in python3, you might have some issues.

Answer (score 29):

Speaking about DP solution, I found it surprising that no one mentioned the fact that LIS can be reduced to [LCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem). All you need to do is sort the copy of the original sequence, remove all the duplicates and do LCS of them. In pseudocode it is:

```
def LIS(S):
    T = sort(S)
    T = removeDuplicates(T)
    return LCS(S, T)
```

And the full implementation written in Go. You do not need to maintain the whole n^2 DP matrix if you do not need to reconstruct the solution.

```
func lcs(arr1 []int) int {
    arr2 := make([]int, len(arr1))
    for i, v := range arr1 {
        arr2[i] = v
    }
    sort.Ints(arr1)
    arr3 := []int{}
    prev := arr1[0] - 1
    for _, v := range arr1 {
        if v != prev {
            prev = v
            arr3 = append(arr3, v)
        }
    }

    n1, n2 := len(arr1), len(arr3)

    M := make([][]int, n2 + 1)
    e := make([]int, (n1 + 1) * (n2 + 1))
    for i := range M {
        M[i] = e[i * (n1 + 1):(i + 1) * (n1 + 1)]
    }

    for i := 1; i <= n2; i++ {
        for j := 1; j <= n1; j++ {
            if arr2[j - 1] == arr3[i - 1] {
                M[i][j] = M[i - 1][j - 1] + 1
            } else if M[i - 1][j] > M[i][j - 1] {
                M[i][j] = M[i - 1][j]
            } else {
                M[i][j] = M[i][j - 1]
            }
        }
    }

    return M[n2][n1]
}
```

Comment: @max yes, it is kind of written in the answer with LCS, n^2 matrix

Answer (score 10):

The following C++ implementation includes also some code that builds the actual *longest increasing subsequence* using an array called `prev`.

```
std::vector<int> longest_increasing_subsequence (const std::vector<int>& s)
{
    int best_end = 0;
    int sz = s.size();

    if (!sz)
        return std::vector<int>();

    std::vector<int> prev(sz,-1);
    std::vector<int> memo(sz, 0);

    int max_length = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();

    memo[0] = 1;

    for ( auto i = 1; i < sz; ++i)
    {
        for ( auto j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        {
            if ( s[j] < s[i] && memo[i] < memo[j] + 1 )
            {
                memo[i] =  memo[j] + 1;
                prev[i] =  j;
            }
        }

        if ( memo[i] > max_length ) 
        {
            best_end = i;
            max_length = memo[i];
        }
    }

    // Code that builds the longest increasing subsequence using "prev"
    std::vector<int> results;
    results.reserve(sz);

    std::stack<int> stk;
    int current = best_end;

    while (current != -1)
    {
        stk.push(s[current]);
        current = prev[current];
    }

    while (!stk.empty())
    {
        results.push_back(stk.top());
        stk.pop();
    }

    return results;
}
```

Implementation with no stack just reverse the vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
std::vector<int> LIS( const std::vector<int> &v ) {
  auto sz = v.size();
  if(!sz)
    return v;
  std::vector<int> memo(sz, 0);
  std::vector<int> prev(sz, -1);
  memo[0] = 1;
  int best_end = 0;
  int max_length = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
  for (auto i = 1; i < sz; ++i) {
    for ( auto j = 0; j < i ; ++j) {
      if (s[j] < s[i] && memo[i] < memo[j] + 1) {
        memo[i] = memo[j] + 1;
        prev[i] = j;
      }
    }
    if(memo[i] > max_length) {
      best_end = i;
      max_length = memo[i];
    }
  }

  // create results
  std::vector<int> results;
  results.reserve(v.size());
  auto current = best_end;
  while (current != -1) {
    results.push_back(s[current]);
    current = prev[current];
  }
  std::reverse(results.begin(), results.end());
  return results;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are three steps of evaluating the problem from dynamic programming point of view:

1. Recurrence definition: maxLength(i) == 1 + maxLength(j) where 0 < j < i and array[i] > array[j]
2. Recurrence parameter boundary: there might be 0 to i - 1 sub-sequences passed as a paramter
3. Evaluation order: as it is increasing sub-sequence, it has to be evaluated from 0 to n

If we take as an example sequence {0, 8, 2, 3, 7, 9}, at index:

- [0] we'll get subsequence {0} as a base case
- [1] we have 1 new subsequence {0, 8}
- [2] trying to evaluate two new sequences {0, 8, 2} and {0, 2} by adding element at index 2 to existing sub-sequences - only one is valid, so adding third possible sequence {0, 2} only to parameters list
  ...

Here's the working C++11 code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int getLongestIncSub(const std::vector<int> &sequence, size_t index, std::vector<std::vector<int>> &sub) {
    if(index == 0) {
        sub.push_back(std::vector<int>{sequence[0]});
        return 1;
    }

    size_t longestSubSeq = getLongestIncSub(sequence, index - 1, sub);
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> tmpSubSeq;
    for(std::vector<int> &subSeq : sub) {
        if(subSeq[subSeq.size() - 1] < sequence[index]) {
            std::vector<int> newSeq(subSeq);
            newSeq.push_back(sequence[index]);
            longestSubSeq = std::max(longestSubSeq, newSeq.size());
            tmpSubSeq.push_back(newSeq);
        }
    }
    std::copy(tmpSubSeq.begin(), tmpSubSeq.end(),
              std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>(sub));

    return longestSubSeq;
}

int getLongestIncSub(const std::vector<int> &sequence) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> sub;
    return getLongestIncSub(sequence, sequence.size() - 1, sub);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> seq{0, 8, 2, 3, 7, 9};
    std::cout << getLongestIncSub(seq);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the recurrence definition should be maxLength(i) = 1 + max(maxLength(j)) for 0 < j < i and array[i] > array[j] rather than without the max().

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Scala implementation of the O(n^2) algorithm:

```
object Solve {
  def longestIncrSubseq[T](xs: List[T])(implicit ord: Ordering[T]) = {
    xs.foldLeft(List[(Int, List[T])]()) {
      (sofar, x) =>
        if (sofar.isEmpty) List((1, List(x)))
        else {
          val resIfEndsAtCurr = (sofar, xs).zipped map {
            (tp, y) =>
              val len = tp._1
              val seq = tp._2
              if (ord.lteq(y, x)) {
                (len + 1, x :: seq) // reversely recorded to avoid O(n)
              } else {
                (1, List(x))
              }
          }
          sofar :+ resIfEndsAtCurr.maxBy(_._1)
        }
    }.maxBy(_._1)._2.reverse
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    println(longestIncrSubseq(List(
      0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15)))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another O(n^2) JAVA implementation. No recursion/memoization to generate the actual subsequence. Just a string array that stores the actual LIS at every stage and an array to store the length of the LIS for each element. Pretty darn easy. Have a look:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 * Created by Shreyans on 4/16/2015
 */

class LNG_INC_SUB//Longest Increasing Subsequence
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter Numbers Separated by Spaces to find their LIS\n");
        String[] s1=br.readLine().split(" ");
        int n=s1.length;
        int[] a=new int[n];//Array actual of Numbers
        String []ls=new String[n];// Array of Strings to maintain LIS for every element
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            a[i]=Integer.parseInt(s1[i]);
        }
        int[]dp=new int[n];//Storing length of max subseq.
        int max=dp[0]=1;//Defaults
        String seq=ls[0]=s1[0];//Defaults
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
            dp[i]=1;
            String x="";
            for(int j=i-1;j>=0;j--)
            {
                //First check if number at index j is less than num at i.
                // Second the length of that DP should be greater than dp[i]
                // -1 since dp of previous could also be one. So we compare the dp[i] as empty initially
                if(a[j]<a[i]&&dp[j]>dp[i]-1)
                {
                    dp[i]=dp[j]+1;//Assigning temp length of LIS. There may come along a bigger LIS of a future a[j]
                    x=ls[j];//Assigning temp LIS of a[j]. Will append a[i] later on
                }
            }
            x+=(" "+a[i]);
            ls[i]=x;
            if(dp[i]>max)
            {
                max=dp[i];
                seq=ls[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Length of LIS is: " + max + "\nThe Sequence is: " + seq);
    }
}
```

Code in action: http://ideone.com/sBiOQx

Answer (score 1):

here is java O(nlogn) implementation

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LongestIncreasingSeq {


    private static int binarySearch(int table[],int a,int len){

        int end = len-1;
        int beg = 0;
        int mid = 0;
        int result = -1;
        while(beg <= end){
            mid = (end + beg) / 2;
            if(table[mid] < a){
                beg=mid+1;
                result = mid;
            }else if(table[mid] == a){
                return len-1;
            }else{
                end = mid-1;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        
//        int[] t = {1, 2, 5,9,16};
//        System.out.println(binarySearch(t , 9, 5));
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = in.nextInt();//4;
        
        int A[] = new int[size];
        int table[] = new int[A.length]; 
        int k = 0;
        while(k<size){
            A[k++] = in.nextInt();
            if(k<size-1)
                in.nextLine();
        }        
        table[0] = A[0];
        int len = 1; 
        for (int i = 1; i < A.length; i++) {
            if(table[0] > A[i]){
                table[0] = A[i];
            }else if(table[len-1]<A[i]){
                table[len++]=A[i];
            }else{
                table[binarySearch(table, A[i],len)+1] = A[i];
            }            
        }
        System.out.println(len);
    }    
}
```

//TreeSet can be used

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in O(n^2) using Dynamic Programming. Python code for the same would be like:-

```
def LIS(numlist):
    LS = [1]
    for i in range(1, len(numlist)):
        LS.append(1)
        for j in range(0, i):
            if numlist[i] > numlist[j] and LS[i]<=LS[j]:
                LS[i] = 1 + LS[j]
    print LS
    return max(LS)

numlist = map(int, raw_input().split(' '))
print LIS(numlist)
```

For input:`5 19 5 81 50 28 29 1 83 23`

output would be:`[1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 1, 5, 3]
5`

The list_index of output list is the list_index of input list. The value at a given list_index in output list denotes the Longest increasing subsequence length for that list_index.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Java implementation in O(n^2). I just did not use Binary Search to find the smallest element in S, which is >= than X. I just used a for loop. Using Binary Search would make the complexity at O(n logn)

```
public static void olis(int[] seq){

    int[] memo = new int[seq.length];

    memo[0] = seq[0];
    int pos = 0;

    for (int i=1; i<seq.length; i++){

        int x = seq[i];

            if (memo[pos] < x){ 
                pos++;
                memo[pos] = x;
            } else {

                for(int j=0; j<=pos; j++){
                    if (memo[j] >= x){
                        memo[j] = x;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            //just to print every step
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(memo));
    }

    //the final array with the LIS
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(memo));
    System.out.println("The length of lis is " + (pos + 1));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

checkout the code in java for longest increasing subsequence with the array elements

http://ideone.com/Nd2eba

```
/**
 **    Java Program to implement Longest Increasing Subsequence Algorithm
 **/

import java.util.Scanner;

/** Class  LongestIncreasingSubsequence **/
 class  LongestIncreasingSubsequence
{
    /** function lis **/
    public int[] lis(int[] X)
    {        
        int n = X.length - 1;
        int[] M = new int[n + 1];  
        int[] P = new int[n + 1]; 
        int L = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++)
        {
            int j = 0;

            /** Linear search applied here. Binary Search can be applied too.
                binary search for the largest positive j <= L such that 
                X[M[j]] < X[i] (or set j = 0 if no such value exists) **/

            for (int pos = L ; pos >= 1; pos--)
            {
                if (X[M[pos]] < X[i])
                {
                    j = pos;
                    break;
                }
            }            
            P[i] = M[j];
            if (j == L || X[i] < X[M[j + 1]])
            {
                M[j + 1] = i;
                L = Math.max(L,j + 1);
            }
        }

        /** backtrack **/

        int[] result = new int[L];
        int pos = M[L];
        for (int i = L - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            result[i] = X[pos];
            pos = P[pos];
        }
        return result;             
    }

    /** Main Function **/
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {    
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Longest Increasing Subsequence Algorithm Test\n");

        System.out.println("Enter number of elements");
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[n + 1];
        System.out.println("\nEnter "+ n +" elements");
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            arr[i] = scan.nextInt();

        LongestIncreasingSubsequence obj = new LongestIncreasingSubsequence(); 
        int[] result = obj.lis(arr);       

        /** print result **/ 

        System.out.print("\nLongest Increasing Subsequence : ");
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
            System.out.print(result[i] +" ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in O(n^2) using dynamic programming.

Process the input elements in order and maintain a list of tuples for each element. Each tuple (A,B), for the element i will denotes, A = length of longest increasing sub-sequence ending at i and B = index of predecessor of list[i] in the longest increasing sub-sequence ending at list[i].

Start from element 1, the list of tuple for element 1 will be [(1,0)]
for element i, scan the list 0..i and find element list[k] such that list[k] < list[i], the value of A for element i, Ai will be Ak + 1 and Bi will be k. If there are multiple such elements, add them to the list of tuples for element i.

In the end, find all the elements with max value of A (length of LIS ending at element) and backtrack using the tuples to get the list.

I have shared the code for same at http://www.edufyme.com/code/?id=66f041e16a60928b05a7e228a89c3799

Comment: You should include the code in your answer as links may break.

Answer (score 0):

O(n^2) java implementation:

```
void LIS(int arr[]){
        int maxCount[]=new int[arr.length];
        int link[]=new int[arr.length];
        int maxI=0;
        link[0]=0;
        maxCount[0]=0;

        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if(arr[j]<arr[i] && ((maxCount[j]+1)>maxCount[i])){
                    maxCount[i]=maxCount[j]+1;
                    link[i]=j;
                    if(maxCount[i]>maxCount[maxI]){
                        maxI=i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]+"   "+link[i]);
        }
        print(arr,maxI,link);

    }

    void print(int arr[],int index,int link[]){
        if(link[index]==index){
            System.out.println(arr[index]+" ");
            return;
        }else{
            print(arr, link[index], link);
            System.out.println(arr[index]+" ");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def longestincrsub(arr1):
    n=len(arr1)
    l=[1]*n
    for i in range(0,n):
        for j in range(0,i)  :
            if arr1[j]<arr1[i] and l[i]<l[j] + 1:
                l[i] =l[j] + 1
    l.sort()
    return l[-1]
arr1=[10,22,9,33,21,50,41,60]
a=longestincrsub(arr1)
print(a)
```

even though there is a way by which you can solve this in O(nlogn) time(this solves in O(n^2) time) but still this way gives the dynamic programming approach which is also good .

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Leetcode solution using Binary Search:->

```
class Solution:
    def binary_search(self,s,x):
        low=0
        high=len(s)-1
        flag=1
        while low<=high:
              mid=(high+low)//2
              if s[mid]==x:
                 flag=0
                 break
              elif s[mid]<x:
                  low=mid+1
              else:
                 high=mid-1
        if flag:
           s[low]=x
        return s

    def lengthOfLIS(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
         if not nums:
            return 0
         s=[]
         s.append(nums[0])
         for i in range(1,len(nums)):
             if s[-1]<nums[i]:
                s.append(nums[i])
             else:
                 s=self.binary_search(s,nums[i])
         return len(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Simplest LIS solution in C++ with O(nlog(n)) time complexity

```
#include <iostream>
#include "vector"
using namespace std;

// binary search (If value not found then it will return the index where the value should be inserted)
int ceilBinarySearch(vector<int> &a,int beg,int end,int value)
{
    if(beg<=end)
    {
        int mid = (beg+end)/2;
        if(a[mid] == value)
            return mid;
        else if(value < a[mid])
            return ceilBinarySearch(a,beg,mid-1,value);
        else
            return ceilBinarySearch(a,mid+1,end,value);

    return 0;
    }

    return beg;

}
int lis(vector<int> arr)
{
    vector<int> dp(arr.size(),0);
    int len = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<arr.size();i++)
    {
        int j = ceilBinarySearch(dp,0,len-1,arr[i]);
        dp[j] = arr[i];
        if(j == len)
            len++;

    }
    return len;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> arr  {2, 5,-1,0,6,1,2};
    cout<<lis(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:
    4

Answer (score 0):

Longest Increasing Subsequence(Java)

```
import java.util.*;

class ChainHighestValue implements Comparable<ChainHighestValue>{
    int highestValue;
    int chainLength;
    ChainHighestValue(int highestValue,int chainLength) {
        this.highestValue = highestValue;
        this.chainLength = chainLength;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(ChainHighestValue o) {
       return this.chainLength-o.chainLength;
    }

}


public class LongestIncreasingSubsequenceLinkedList {


    private static LinkedList<Integer> LongestSubsequent(int arr[], int size){
        ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> seqList=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<ChainHighestValue> valuePairs=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            int currValue=arr[i];
            if(valuePairs.size()==0){
                LinkedList<Integer> aList=new LinkedList<>();
                aList.add(arr[i]);
                seqList.add(aList);
                valuePairs.add(new ChainHighestValue(arr[i],1));

            }else{
                try{
                    ChainHighestValue heighestIndex=valuePairs.stream().filter(e->e.highestValue<currValue).max(ChainHighestValue::compareTo).get();
                    int index=valuePairs.indexOf(heighestIndex);
                    seqList.get(index).add(arr[i]);
                    heighestIndex.highestValue=arr[i];
                    heighestIndex.chainLength+=1;

                }catch (Exception e){
                    LinkedList<Integer> aList=new LinkedList<>();
                    aList.add(arr[i]);
                    seqList.add(aList);
                    valuePairs.add(new ChainHighestValue(arr[i],1));
                }
            }
        }
        ChainHighestValue heighestIndex=valuePairs.stream().max(ChainHighestValue::compareTo).get();
        int index=valuePairs.indexOf(heighestIndex);
        return seqList.get(index);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int arry[]={5,1,3,6,11,30,32,5,3,73,79};
        //int arryB[]={3,1,5,2,6,4,9};
        LinkedList<Integer> LIS=LongestSubsequent(arry, arry.length);
        System.out.println("Longest Incrementing Subsequence:");
        for(Integer a: LIS){
            System.out.print(a+" ");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented LIS in java using Dynamic Programming and Memoization. Along with the code I have done complexity calculation i.e. why it is O(n Log(base2) n). As I feel theoretical or logical explanations are good but practical demonstration is always better for understanding.

```
package com.company.dynamicProgramming;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LongestIncreasingSequence {

    static int complexity = 0;

    public static void main(String ...args){


        int[] arr = {10, 22, 9, 33, 21, 50, 41, 60, 80};
        int n = arr.length;

        Map<Integer, Integer> memo = new HashMap<>();

        lis(arr, n, memo);

        //Display Code Begins
        int x = 0;
        System.out.format("Longest Increasing Sub-Sequence with size %S is -> ",memo.get(n));
        for(Map.Entry e : memo.entrySet()){

            if((Integer)e.getValue() > x){
                System.out.print(arr[(Integer)e.getKey()-1] + " ");
                x++;
            }
        }
        System.out.format("%nAnd Time Complexity for Array size %S is just %S ", arr.length, complexity );
        System.out.format( "%nWhich is equivalent to O(n Log n) i.e. %SLog(base2)%S is %S",arr.length,arr.length, arr.length * Math.ceil(Math.log(arr.length)/Math.log(2)));
        //Display Code Ends

    }



    static int lis(int[] arr, int n, Map<Integer, Integer> memo){

        if(n==1){
            memo.put(1, 1);
            return 1;
        }

        int lisAti;
        int lisAtn = 1;

        for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
            complexity++;

            if(memo.get(i)!=null){
                lisAti = memo.get(i);
            }else {
                lisAti = lis(arr, i, memo);
            }

            if(arr[i-1] < arr[n-1] && lisAti +1 > lisAtn){
                lisAtn = lisAti +1;
            }
        }

        memo.put(n, lisAtn);
        return lisAtn;

    }
}
```

While I ran the above code -

```
Longest Increasing Sub-Sequence with size 6 is -> 10 22 33 50 60 80 
And Time Complexity for Array size 9 is just 36 
Which is equivalent to O(n Log n) i.e. 9Log(base2)9 is 36.0
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Gives wrong answer for input: {0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15};

Answer (score 0):

**The O(NLog(N)) Approach To Find Longest Increasing Sub sequence**
Let us maintain an array where the ith element is the smallest possible number with which a i sized sub sequence can end.

On purpose I am avoiding further details as the top voted answer already explains it, but this technique eventually leads to a neat implementation using the set data structure (at least in c++).

Here is the implementation in c++ (assuming strictly increasing longest sub sequence size is required)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> // gcc supported header to include (almost) everything
using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;

int main()
{
  ll n;
  cin >> n;
  ll arr[n];
  set<ll> S;

  for(ll i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    cin >> arr[i];
    auto it = S.lower_bound(arr[i]);
    if(it != S.end())
      S.erase(it);
    S.insert(arr[i]);
  }

  cout << S.size() << endl; // Size of the set is the required answer

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### The O(NLog(N)) Recursive DP Approach To Finding the Longest Increasing Subsequence (LIS)

---

**Explanation**

This algorithm involves creating a tree with node format as `(a,b)`.

`a` represents the next element we are considering appending to the valid subsequence so far.

`b` represents the starting index of the remaining subarray that the next decision will be made from if `a` gets appended to the end of the subarray we have so far.

**Algorithm**

1. We start with an invalid root (INT_MIN,0), pointing at index zero of the array since subsequence is empty at this point, i.e. `b = 0`.
2. `Base Case`: return `1` if `b >= array.length`.
3. Loop through all the elements in the array from the `b` index to the end of the array, i.e `i = b ... array.length-1`.
   i) If an element, `array[i]` is `greater than` the current `a`, it is qualified to be considered as one of the elements to be appended to the subsequence we have so far.
   ii)  Recurse into the node `(array[i],b+1)`, where `a` is the element we encountered in `2(i)` which is qualified to be appended to the subsequence we have so far. And `b+1` is the next index of the array to be considered.
   iii) Return the `max` length obtained by looping through `i = b ... array.length`. In a case where `a` is bigger than any other element from `i = b to array.length`, return `1`.
4. Compute the level of the tree built as `level`. Finally, `level - 1` is the desired `LIS`. That is the number of `edges` in the longest path of the tree.

**NB**: The memorization part of the algorithm is left out since it's clear from the tree.

**Random Example**
Nodes marked `x` are fetched from the DB memoized values.
[image]

**Java Implementation**

```
public int lengthOfLIS(int[] nums) {
            return LIS(nums,Integer.MIN_VALUE, 0,new HashMap<>()) -1;
    }
    public int LIS(int[] arr, int value, int nextIndex, Map<String,Integer> memo){
        if(memo.containsKey(value+","+nextIndex))return memo.get(value+","+nextIndex);
        if(nextIndex >= arr.length)return 1;

        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for(int i=nextIndex; i<arr.length; i++){
            if(arr[i] > value){
                max = Math.max(max,LIS(arr,arr[i],i+1,memo));
            }
        }
        if(max == Integer.MIN_VALUE)return 1;
        max++;
        memo.put(value+","+nextIndex,max);
        return max;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **dynamic programming** [Approach 1], this problem can be solved in `theta(n^2`) times and below is the code for it.

```
def lis_dp(array):
    alias = [1] * len(array)
    for i in range(1, len(array)):
        for j in range(0, i):
            if array[i] > array[j]:
                alias[i] = max(alias[i], alias[j] + 1)

    output = max(alias)
    return output


arr = [4, 10, 6, 5, 8, 11, 2, 20]
output = lis_dp(array=arr)
print(output)
```

**Analyse of Time complexity of approach 1:** It is `theta(n^2)` as two for loops are used in this code.

**Second approach: Using Binary search**

This problem can be solved in `theta(nlog(n))` time.

**Theory:**

Tail array is constructed and length of tail array is the answer.

**tail[i]** stores the minimum possible tail value for LIS of length (i + 1) where i range from (0, n), where n is length of given array.

**Two conditions while creating tail array**

**Condition 1:** If the next element to be inserted in the tail array is greater than previous one, then element is appended.

**Condition 2:** If the next element to be inserted in the tail array is smaller than previous element then it will replace it ceiling to its left.

**Corner case**

**Case 1:** If we have array sorted in descending order, output is 1

**Case 2:** If we have array sorted in ascending order, output is length(array)

**Note:** Corner cases remains same for both dynamic programming or binary search approach.

Let us see the code for approach 2

```
def ceil_idx(tail, x):
    l = 0
    r = len(tail) - 1
    while r > l:
      m = l + (r - l)//2
      if tail[m] >= x:
        r = m
      else:
        l = m + 1
    return r


def lis_bs(array):
    n = len(array)
    tail = [array[0]]

    for i in range(1, n):
         # condition 1: If the next element to be inserted in the tail array is greater than previous one, then element is appended.
       if array[i] > tail[-1]:
         tail.append(array[i])
       else:
         # condition 2: If the next element to be inserted in the tail array is smaller than previous element then it will replace it ceiling to its left.
         c = ceil_idx(tail, array[i])
         tail[c] = array[i]

    return len(tail)


arr = [4, 10, 6, 5, 8, 11, 2, 20]
output_lis = lis_bs(array=arr)
print(output_lis)
```

**Analyse of** **Time complexity of second approach**

Since there is for loop which run till length of array, hence will take theta(n) times and inside this loop there runs another function which is binary search (ceiling function) which takes log(n) times and hence total time taken is **nlog(n)**.