# Maximum Length of Pairs in increasing order

Tags: java, algorithm

Given n pairs of numbers the first number is always smaller than the second number. A pair (c, d) can follow a pair (a, b) if and only if b <= c. Chain of pairs can be formed in this fashion. Find the longest chain which can be formed from a given set of pairs.

e.g. `{ (1,2), (3,4), (5,7), (9,10), (7,9), (8,9), (0,6) }`

So the output should be : `{(1,2), (3,4), (5,7), (8,9), (9,10)}`

My Algorithm for this is as below:

```
 1. Sort the list according to the 2nd number of elements
i.e.`{ (1,2), (3,4), (0,6), (5,7), (7,9), (8,9), (9,10)  }`
 2. choose the first element from the list  i.e. `(1,2)`
 3. for each element e in the list left
      4. choose this element e if the first number of the element is greater than the 2nd number of the previous element. i.e. after `(1,2)` choose `(3,4)` because `3 > 2.`
```

After the above algorithm you will have the output as `{(1,2), (3,4), (5,7), (8,9), (9,10)}`.

Please let me know about the correctness of the algorithm. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

A more intuitive proof of correctness:

> Proof: The only way to include more pairs in the chain is to replace a pair with one with a smaller Y value, to allow for the next
>   pair to have a smaller X value, potentially fitting another pair where
>   it couldn't fit before. If you replace a pair with one with the same Y
>   value, you gain nothing. If the replacement has a larger Y value, all
>   you've done is potentially block some pairs that would've fit before.
>
> Because the pairs have been sorted by Y values, you will never find a replacement with a smaller Y. Looking "forward" in the sorted
>   pairs, they will all have the same or greater Y value. Looking
>   "backward", any that were eliminated from the chain initially were
>   because the X value wasn't high enough, which will still be the case.

This is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530303/longest-chain-of-pairs)

Comment: Why do you leave the pair (7,9) out? Why does it not come after the pair (5,7)?

Comment: Another valid chain given your example is {(1,2), (3,4), (5,7), (7,9), (9,10)}. Do you desire to find both / all chains, either chain, maximum length chain, or something else?

Comment: @user1676075 `Find the longest chain`

Comment: @arjacsoh ya it can come also but either (5,7) or (8,9) can be present at a given point in time.

Comment: @Gamb Are you sure? If that was the case, something like (1, 10000) would still be likely to get into the list

Comment: I don't think this will work because it's greedy. There could be a longer chain from excluding one element that is included. I think this needs to be done as a dynamic program.

Comment: Your algorithm is greedy and won't work for some sets: (1,2) (3,10) (4,5) (6,7) (8,9). Your algorithm will choose (1,2) (3,10). To solve it you must implement dynamic programming algorithm.

Comment: @gawi You're missing the fact that it sorts by second element first

Comment: @gawi Agreed. This seems to be a variant on the knapsack problem.

Comment: @StephenTG Maybe I missed the sorting order - but in general this problem can be solved exactly by DP, not a greedy algorithm

Comment: @gawi first of all it should be sorted on top of the 2nd number of the individual element.

Comment: @gawi With your list, his algorithm should grab (1,2), (4,5), (6,7) (8,9)

Comment: @StephenTG which is correct i feel.

Comment: This question is asking for a code review not presenting a problem. This question is more suited to CodeReview.

Comment: @Trying Certainly in that example, as there's no way of fitting (3,10) in anything but a two element chain

Comment: For what it's worth, your algorithm is correct. I might post a proof a bit later.

Comment: @IVlad Sure i will wait for your proof thanks IVlad

Comment: OK, Agree, I made a mistake - sorting stuff led me to wrong conclusions - usually you sort to decrease searching space, however in this case you can have to search all pairs anyway, and time complexity in worst case scenario doesn't change

Comment: Why does `(7, 9)` follows `(9,10)` does it violate `b <= c`?

Comment: @IVlad: I doubt that the OP is allowed to sort the chain.

Comment: @Groo Never said he couldn't. Plus, that's the first step he lists in his algorithm

Comment: @Groo - why wouldn't he be? According to his example, the picked pairs do not have to be picked in the relative order that they appear in.

Comment: @IVlad: right, sorry, I missed that. I thought it was a classic subsequence problem.

Comment: @IVlad: but I still doubt that the optimum solution to this problem always has to start with the element which has the lowest 2nd item? Need to examine it a bit thoroughly, but it just feels strange.

Comment: @Groo Consider a chain `C`, with first element `(c,d)`. Now consider an element (not in the chain) `(a,b)` where `b < d` (thus making it the element with the lowest 2nd item in the new set `{C + (a,b)}`). If `b <= c` then the new element may be added to `C`, making the length longer; if `b > c`, `(c,d)` may be replaced by `(a,b)`, and, because `b<d ==> b< whatever's next`, the rest of the chain (and thus its length) is unchanged. _One_ of the optimum solutions will start with the element w/ the lowest 2nd item (there may be others, but all the same length).

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: yes, you're right, that makes sense. The fact that it's allowed to pick them in arbitrary order completely screwed my reasoning, but it's actually rather simple.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat and of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530303/longest-chain-of-pairs

Comment: @DavidEisenstat the link that you have mentioned and this question are not same. Please verify. thanks.

Comment: You're right, it's a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530303/longest-chain-of-pairs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct. Here's a proof:

Let `s1, s2, ..., sl` be the pairs found by your algorithm and `i1, i2, ..., ik` be an optimal solution.

We have:

```
l == k => your algorithm is obviously correct, since it's clear that
          it doesn't produce invalid solutions;

l > k => this would contradict our hypothesis that i1, ..., ik is optimal,
         so it makes no sense to bother with this;

l < k => this would mean that your algorithm is wrong. 
         Let's assume this is the case.
```

Assume `i1 != s1`. In this case, we can replace `i1` with `s1` in the optimal solution, since `s1` is the pair with the lowest finish time. So `s1, i2, ..., ik` remains an optimal solution.

Let `t <= l` be the first index for which `st != it`. Therefore, `s1, s2, ..., s[t-1], it, ...` is an optimal solution. We can replace `it` with `st` because:

- `st` is not part of the first `t-1` elements of the optimal solution;
- `st` is not part of `i[t+1], ..., ik`. If it were, that would mean that `st` started after `it` finished, which would contradict the way the algorithm selects `st`.

Therefore, continuing in this fashion, our optimal solution is `s1, s2, ..., sl, ..., ik`. This means that it is possible to add more pairs after `sl`, but this contradicts the way the algorithm works, so we have `l = k`, and the algorithm is correct.

Answer (score 2):

1. pair `(c, d)` can follow a pair `(a, b)` iff `b <= c`
2. pair `(c, d)` has constraint `d > c`

Therfore we can, say

```
b <= c
```

becomes

```
b < d because d > c
```

Therefore longest sequence would start with smallest second element. Therefore you sort them according to second element select first element and compare as per your original condition `b <= c`

Algorithm is correct. As you get the first element (greedy) and then you are keeping the original constraint intact that is `b <= c`.

Note:
You can not use `b < d` conditions for comparing elements after sorting, because you cannot deduce `b <= c` (original condition) from `b < d` but other way around is possible.

Comment: i like this proof. more intuitive. +1

Answer (score -1):

This problem can be solved too many ways 
Same type of problem is already there check it
You are given n pairs of numbers. In every pair, the first number is always smaller than the second number. A pair (c, d) can follow another pair (a, b) if b < c. Chain of pairs can be formed in this fashion. Find the longest chain which can be formed from a given set of pairs.

You can go here and there are so many useful resource are there

[MaximumLengthChainoofPairs](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-20-maximum-length-chain-of-pairs/)

[LongestIncreasingSequence](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-3-longest-increasing-subsequence/)

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Those are not the same thing because they involve selecting the elements in the order that they appear in.

Comment: @Joel what about(0,6)?

Comment: [@Shivaram Kalra](http://stackoverflow.com/users/858926/shivam-kalra)why not considering(0,6)..this is corner case or longest sequential

Comment: @Envious my algorithm is different from the one that you have posted. I know this can be solved in LIS but this is O(NLogN) algorithm and i feel easier to understand. One more thing i know LIS can be solved in O(NLogN) but thats little bit tricky. Thanks.