# simpest way to get the longest sequence of sorted elements from a given unsorted integer vector in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, sorting

I have an unsorted array and need to extract the longest sequence of sorted elements.
For instance

A = 2,4,1,7,4,5,0,8,65,4,2,34

here 0,8,65 is my target sequence

I need to keep track of the index where this sequence starts

Comment: how did you know that `0,8,65` is your target sequence ?

Comment: those elements are sorted and are 3

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine the longest increasing subsequence using dynamic programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631726/how-to-determine-the-longest-increasing-subsequence-using-dynamic-programming)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it in linear time `O(N)` with this algorithm: construct vector `len` of the same size `N` as the original vector, such that `len[i]` contains the length of the longest consecutive ascending run to which element `seq[i]` belongs.

The value of `len[i]` can be calculated as follows:

```
len[0] = 1;
for (int i = 1 ; i != N ; i++) {
    len[i] = seq[i-1] >= seq[i] ? 1 : len[i-1]+1;
}
```

With `len` in hand, find the index of `max(len)` element. This is the last element of your run. Track back to `len[j] == 1` to find the initial element of the run.

```
seq    len
---    ---
  2      1
  4      2
  1      1
  7      2
  4      1
  5      2
  0      1
  8      2
 65      3 << MAX
  4      1
  2      1
 34      2
```

Note that at each step of the algorithm you need only the element `len[i-1]` to calculate `len`, so you can optimize for constant space by dropping vector representation of `len` and keeping the prior one, the `max_len`, and `max_len_index`.

Here is this algorithm optimized for constant space. Variable `len` represents `len[i-1]` from the linear-space algorithm.

```
int len = 1, pos = 0, maxlen = 1, current_start = 0;
for (int i = 1 ; i < seq.size() ; i++) {
    if (seq[i] > seq[i-1]) {
        len++;
        if (len > maxlen) {
            maxlen = len;
            pos = current_start;
        }
    } else {
        len = 1;
        current_start = i;
    }
}
```

Here is [a link to this program on ideone](http://ideone.com/E92rE).

Comment: This is not the simplest way ! Besides, it is unnatural,i.e. if you didn't see a similar solution previously, you're highly unlikely to come up with it; and it uses more memory than needed.

Comment: @Razvan This is as trivial as dynamic programming algorithms go. I do agree about the "unlikely" part, but that's true of any non-trivial algorithm.

Comment: Woah! O(N) memory for this? Keep it simple and cheap instead.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri Thanks for noticing it, this is now fixed.

Comment: I stand corrected! Not sure the O(N) explanation adds much for me, but you're quite right. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 5):

You need 4 indexes (begin, end, tmp_begin, tmp_end). Iterate through the original array using `tmp_begin`, `tmp_end` as the work indexes and each time you find a longer sorted sequence update `begin` and `end` indices.

To check that a subsequence is sorted, you have to check that element at i is greater than element at i-- for each pair of consecutive items in the subsequence.

In the end: print all the elements in the original array starting at `begin` and ending at `end`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<size_of_array;i++)
{
  iterate++;
  after=array[iterate];
  if(after>before) {current_counter++;} else {current_counter=0;}
  if(max_counter<current_counter) max_counter=current_counter;
  before=array[iterate];
}

printf(" maximum length=%i ",max_counter);
```