# Longest Increasing Subsequence - Not able to understand the actual LIS creation

Tags: java, c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Can someone please explain the last of the algo given by Peter in the article 
[How to determine the longest increasing subsequence using dynamic programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631726/how-to-determine-the-longest-increasing-subsequence-using-dynamic-programming)
I am not able to get the construction of actual LIS, how the parent array will be constructed.
Please explain with the same example which Peter has taken.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean the `O(N log N)` version, right?

Comment: the example: `2 6 3 4 1 2 9 5 8` with solution `1, 2, 4, 5, 8` seem wrong, because no sub-sequence contain `1, 2, 4` in that order, before `4` there is no `1`, that don't mean that the algorithm is wrong.

Comment: @ldgabbay...yes that one only..I want to understand the construction of LIS part..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The longest increasing subsequence in Peter's example is actually "2 3 4 5 8", resulting in length 5.

It is not possible to obtain the LIS by looking at the array `S` at the end of the algorithm and `S` is **not** the longest increasing subsequence.

If we need to construct the LIS, we will need to store more information and modify the algorithm that is presented. Peter has mentioned storing `parent[i]` and changing `S[i]` to store indexes instead of values in the later part of this article.

Let me modify his proposed algorithm and define `Si` to store the index of the numbers in the array `S` and `parent[i]` to store the index of the previous number in the LIS that ends at `array[i]`.
Using his example: `array[] = {2, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2, 9, 5, 8}`. Do note that `-1` is used in the parent array when they form LIS of maximum length 1.

```
0. S = {} - Initialize S to the empty set
   Si = {}
   parent = {}
1. S = {2} - New largest LIS
   Si = {0}
   parent = {-1}
2. S = {2, 6} - New largest LIS
   Si = {**0**, 1}
   parent = {-1, **0**}
3. S = {2, 3} - Changed 6 to 3
   Si = {**0**, 2}
   parent = {-1, 0, **0**}
4. S = {2, 3, 4} - New largest LIS
   Si = {0, **2**, 3}
   parent = {-1, 0, 0, **2**}
5. S = {1, 3, 4} - Changed 2 to 1
   Si = {4, 2, 3}
   parent = {-1, 0, 0, 2, -1}
6. S = {1, 2, 4} - Changed 3 to 2
   Si = {**4**, 5, 3}
   parent = {-1, 0, 0, 2, -1, **4**}
7. S = {1, 2, 4, 9} - New largest LIS
   Si = {4, 5, **3**, 6}
   parent = {-1, 0, 0, 2, -1, 4, **3**}
8. S = {1, 2, 4, 5} - Changed 9 to 5
   Si = {4, 5, **3**, 7}
   parent = {-1, 0, 0, 2, -1, 4, 3, **3**}
9. S = {1, 2, 4, 5, 8} - New largest LIS
   Si = {4, 5, 3, **7**, 8}
   parent = {-1, 0, 0, 2, -1, 4, 3, 3, 7}
```

At the end, we get the parent array `{-1, 0, 0, 2, -1, 4, 3, 3, 7}`

1) by looking at `S`, we know there is an LIS of length 5 ending at index 8 with value 8. 
`LIS = { ?, ?, ?, ?, 8 }`

2) we now look at the parent of index 8, `parent[8]` is 7 and the preceding member of the LIS will be in index 7. This is the number 5.
`LIS = { ?, ?, ?, 5, 8 }`

3) we now look at the parent of index 7 (value 5), `parent[7]` is 3 and the previous member of the LIS will be in index 3. This is the number 4.
`LIS = { ?, ?, 4, 5, 8 }`

4) we now look at the parent of index 3 (value 4), `parent[3]` is 2 and the previous member of the LIS will be in index 2. This is the number 3.
`LIS = { ?, 3, 4, 5, 8 }`

5) we now look at the parent of index 2 (value 3), `parent[2]` is 0 and the previous member of the LIS will be in index 0. This is the number 2.
`LIS = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 8 }`

6) The actual LIS would be `2 3 4 5 8`.

Comment: so u mean tht the algorithm by him is not in sequence...like first get the length and then construct the actual LIS?

Comment: I have elaborated more above :)

Comment: Thanks a lot...I got it now... :)