# Longest non-decreasing sub-sequence in O(nlogn)

Tags: algorithm, implementation, lis

This may be a very classical problem of finding longest non-decreasing subsequence in O(nlogn). Just to revise, length of longest non-decreasing subsequence in array A={2 4 2 3 3 5 1} is 5 {2 2 3 3 5}.

However, After countless efforts I fail to understand where my implementation of the algorithm is failing. I've read and implementing the algorithm described [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631726/how-to-determine-the-longest-increasing-subsequence-using-dynamic-programming) and [Here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-monotonically-increasing-subsequence-size-n-log-n/) with only a little change of "=" sign to allow equal elements in O(nlogn) implementation of longest increasing subsequence. I'm attempting [this](http://www.spoj.com/problems/BRIDGE/) problem where trivial O(n^2) approach (which is correct as the solution got accepted) and O(nlogn) approach are giving different solutions (which I inferred by assert statements) which proves that something is wrong for sure with my O(nlogn) implementation.

My O(nlogn) implementation is as follows:

```
/* Array LNDS will be used for finding
longest non-decreasing subsequence in array A of size n */
int LNDS[n],len=1,x; // len will be storing the required length
fill(LNDS,LNDS+n,0);
LNDS[0]=A[0];
for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
{
    x=LNDS[len-1];
    if(A[i]<LNDS[0])
        LNDS[0]=A[i];
    else if(A[i]>=x) // "=" sign to allow equal elements
        LNDS[len++]=A[i];
    else
    {
        l=0;
        r=len-1;
        while(r-l>1) // binary search for finding lower bound for A[i] in LNDS
        {
            m=(l+r)/2;
            if(LNDS[m]>=A[i]) r=m;
            else l=m;
        }
        LNDS[r]=A[i];
    }
}
return len;
```

Comment: What input/output are you getting for this algorithm?

Comment: Actually I'm getting correct output for all the manually generated input cases I could generate. That's why I couldn't find where the above implementation is failing.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include which test cases you have already tried?  It might help identify a missed test case