# Detecting unsorted elements in an almost sorted array

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a set of samples that is sorted, but due to errors in the data sometimes unsorted values creep in. I need to detect these values and remove them. I'll show some sample datasets below.

> 20 ***30*** 21 22 23 24 25
>
> ***30 31*** 21 22 23 24 25
>
> ***30*** 21 22 23 24 25 26
>
> 20 21 22 23 ***18*** 25 26
>
> 20 ***15*** 21 22 23 24 25

In each case the bold italic numbers are the ones that should be removed. What would be an algorithm to do remove these numbers/detect the indices of these numbers?

Comment: My question is what would be an algorithm to achieve the same. I can explain some approaches I tried if that helps

Comment: Read the array from low index to high index (or vice versa, it hardly matters) and throw out (or otherwise mark) the out-of-sequence values.  You're not going to find a general approach with complexity lower than `O(n)`.  What else might you be thinking of ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark That fails for 2nd test case. You will need to do it repeatidly with this approach, and that's not O(n).

Comment: O(n) is what I am looking for. I want to know how to mark the out-of-sequence elements? Can't use arr[k + 1] < arr[k] as far as I can see.

Comment: You should be looking for the [longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence). See also: [Remove unsorted/outlier elements in nearly-sorted array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32217310/3789665)

Comment: @greybeard Thanks. That should solve my problem. Out of curiosity, if the second case was not there, i.e out of sequence elements were limited to a single digit, what would be the steps? Might be my sleep ridden brain, but I can't seem to figure out a way for that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Detecting is relatively simpler and takes less steps - you could do it in `O(n)` time. Simply iterate over the array and compare each element to the next. You would be able to find (and mark indices or throw-out) out-of-sequence numbers.

However, your second case makes doing this a problem. I will assume that you always want to keep the longest increasing sub-sequence of the list of numbers (like in the 2nd case).

You can solve this problem efficiently with arrays and binary search. The algorithm performs a single binary search per sequence element, its total time can be expressed as `O(n log n)`.

Process the sequence elements in order, maintain the longest increasing sub-sequence found so far. Denote the sequence values as `X[0], X[1]`, etc. `L` representing the length of the longest increasing sub-sequence found so far.

`M[j]` stores the index `k` of the smallest value `X[k]` such that there is an increasing sub-sequence of length `j` ending at `X[k]` on the range `k ≤ i`. `j ≤ k ≤ i` always. `P[k]` stores the index of the predecessor of `X[k]` in the longest increasing sub-sequence ending at `X[k]`

The sequence `X[M[1]], X[M[2]], ..., X[M[L]]` is always nondecreasing at all points of the algorithm.

```
P = array of length N
M = array of length N + 1 // Using a 1 indexed array for ease of understanding

L = 0
for i in range 0 to N-1:
   // Binary search
   lo = 1
   hi = L
   while lo ≤ hi:
       mid = ceil((lo+hi)/2)
       if X[M[mid]] < X[i]:
           lo = mid+1
       else:
           hi = mid-1

newL = lo

P[i] = M[newL-1]
M[newL] = i

if newL > L:
    L = newL

S = array of length L
k = M[L]
for i in range L-1 to 0:
    S[i] = X[k]
    k = P[k]

return S
```

The pseudo-code can be found on the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) for this.

If you do want to keep the out-of-sequence elements in the list, simply sort the array using insertion sort.

Comment: Please give pseudo-code for detection in case of a single unsorted number. I can't iterate over and do "if(arr[k + 1] < arr[k]) throw arr[k + 1]" since that would fail in my 1st case, and I can't do "if(arr[k+1] < arr[k]) throw arr[k]" since that would fail in my 4th case.

Comment: `if(arr[k-1] < arr[k] && arr[k] > arr[k+1] || arr[k-1] > arr[k] && arr[k] < arr[k+1]) throw arr[k]`

Handle corner indices separately.

Answer (score 1):

**Detecting only**

It takes at least N-1 steps to check (check each element and next), to do it.

But it is ambiguous: In list 2, what is wrong ? 30/31, or 21/.../25 ?

If bad numbers are isolated, you just remove them. But if you have, say, 2 numbers, what to do ? You must define more rules.

**Detecting, and sorting :**

**Complexity:**

If your list is perfectly sorted, it takes N-1 steps (check each element and next), to do it.

If there is **one** unsorted element, it takes log N to replace it at good place (if I suppose everything else is sorted, and in a structure ad hoc like binary tree).

It there are k unsorted elements, it will take k log N .

So N (check) + k log N (insert).

And if **everything** is messed, N log N, which is classical complexity for sorting.

**Algorithm:**

So, simpliest algorithm is to iterate, and insert at good place, in a balanced tree. It is a sort by insertion.

It is like smoothsort: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothsort

Comment: @HenkHolterman - yes - implicitely, I suppose Set is binary . I precise my answer.

Comment: If there was only one unsorted element, what would be "N(check)"?

Comment: @diAblo unfortunately, even with one unsorted, you need N (really N-1) iterations to check it.

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work for you. It finds the longest subsequence and then clears up the other elements. The implementation is in c#

```cs
public static void Main() {
    int[][] dataList = {
                        new []{20,30,21,22,23,24,25},
                        new []{30,31,21,22,23,24,25},
                        new []{30,21,22,23,24,25,26},
                        new []{20,21,22,23,18,25,26},
                        new []{20,15,21,22,23,24,25}
                    };

    foreach (var data in dataList)
        DetectAndRemoveUnsorted(data);
}

/// <summary>
/// Assumes ascending data. You can adapt it for descending data too
/// </summary>
static void DetectAndRemoveUnsorted(IList<int> data) {
    // first pass: Find the outliers; rather find the correct sequence
    int startOfLongestSeq = 0, lenOfLongestSeq = 0;
    int startOfCurrSeq = 0, lenOfCurrSeq = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Count - 1; ++i) {
        if (data[i] > data[i + 1]) { // we are breaking the ascending order, so this is another sequence
            lenOfCurrSeq = i - startOfCurrSeq + 1;
            if (lenOfCurrSeq > lenOfLongestSeq) {
                lenOfLongestSeq = lenOfCurrSeq;
                startOfLongestSeq = startOfCurrSeq;
            }
            startOfCurrSeq = i + 1;
        }
    }

    lenOfCurrSeq = data.Count - startOfCurrSeq;
    if (lenOfCurrSeq > lenOfLongestSeq) {
        lenOfLongestSeq = lenOfCurrSeq;
        startOfLongestSeq = startOfCurrSeq;
    }


    // second pass: cleanup outliers

    // now we know which sequence is the largest
    // we should get rid of the other sequences
    for (int i = startOfLongestSeq - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        data[i] = -1; // Mark them as invalid. if you want, you can delete them as well

    for (int i = data.Count - 1; i >= startOfLongestSeq + lenOfLongestSeq; --i)
        data[i] = -1; // Mark them as invalid. if you want, you can delete them as well
}
```

Comment: Down voters, care to explain what's wrong with the solution?