# Longest Increasing Subsequence optimization

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, subsequence

The *Longest Increasing Subsequence* problem is to find a subsequence of a given sequence in which the subsequence's elements are in sorted order and in which the subsequence is as long as possible.

Here is my O(n^2) approach which is running very slow for long input:

```
N = int(input())

lst = []
for i in range(N):
    lst.append(input())

count = [1] * N

for i in range(1, len(lst)):
    for j in range(i):
        if(int(lst[j]) < int(lst[i])):
            k = int(count[j]) + 1
            if (k > int(count[i])):
                count[i] = k
count.sort()
print(count[-1])
```

Can anybody tell me how can it be done in O(n*log n) time?

Comment: When I searched for the algorithm, the *first* DuckDuckGo result was [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence), which has an algorithm *written in Python-like language*...

Comment: And if you need a video explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9oUiVYEq7E&t=0s

Comment: See also: [How to determine the longest increasing subsequence using dynamic programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631726/how-to-determine-the-longest-increasing-subsequence-using-dynamic-programming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great resources have been mentioned in the comments; if you still want a piece of python code, I've written and explained it here.

In this algorithm, for all `L < N`, we keep a track of the values in the input which represent the endpoint of the current longest increasing subsequence of length `L`.

`longest_sequence_values` stores these values. For example, `longest_sequence_values[3]` is a value in the input at which the longest increasing subsequence of length 3 ends.

Note here that `longest_sequence_values` will always be non-decreasing, which allows us to perform a binary search when we're trying to build a new longest increasing subsequence. This happens because if `i < j`, then the endpoint of a subsequence of length `i` cannot be larger than the endpoint of a subsequence of length `j`.

`longest_current_sequence` is the length of of the longest subsequence found thus far. We need this value to specify the range of the binary search. It also represents the answer at the end.

```
from math import ceil
N = int(input())

input_vals = []
for i in range(N):
    input_vals.append(input())

longest_sequence_values = [None] * (N+1)
longest_current_sequence = 0

for i in range(N):
    # binary search starts here
    # this gives us the log(N) factor
    lo = 1
    hi = longest_current_sequence
    while lo <= hi:
        mid = int(ceil((lo+hi)/2))
        if longest_sequence_values[mid] <= input_vals[i]:
            lo = mid + 1
        else:
            hi = mid - 1

    # lo will be length of the longest sequence ending at input_vals[i]
    longest_len_here = lo
    # We have a new lis of length longest_len_here ending at index i
    # Note that before we perform the following substitutions,
    # longest_sequence_values[longest_len_here] >= input_vals[i]
    # This means that the new endpoint of the lis of length longest_len_here
    # is <= to the old endpoint.
    # This point is essential in keeping the result optimal
    longest_sequence_values[longest_len_here] = input_vals[i]

    if longest_len_here > longest_current_sequence:
        longest_current_sequence = longest_len_here

print longest_current_sequence
```

Comment: Your code runs perfectly. Here is my code, It's working fine for some inputs, But for some it's not. It has some bug, can you tell me where am I doing it wrong.

http://paste.ofcode.org/WFqZYpE2e2av4KwhpfSV74

Comment: @Atinesh Can you post some inputs for which it is failing? Ideally, `tailTable` should be dealing with indices in the range `[1, N]` instead of `[0, N]`. This is because the indices represent lengths of size `1..N` and things will be more intuitive that way. Your `binary_search` method looks weak. For some reason the starting range is `[-1, N-1]`. Binary search is used to divide a sorted range into two parts using a property. In this case, that property is 'largest `j < len` such that `tailTable[j] <= key`'. Ensure that this is the case.

Comment: Actually, I tried this code on `Hacker Rank` they have tested it on 9 test cases out of which only 2 are successful. Here is the test case

`Input` : http://paste.ofcode.org/MTCs4irbBFNNndgAGf3yEk
`Expected Output` : 185

Comment: I can't make any useful deductions using a test input of that size. If you can, find a small test case on which your code breaks and post it. I'm pretty sure it's the binary search, though. Change your `tailTable` range from `[0, N-1]` to `[1, N]`, study the binary search that I have used, and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Atinesh I just ran your code on the input you gave and it gave 185, which you said is the expected output...

Comment: I'm getting `189`. Try to run this code
http://paste.ofcode.org/rGbxeeXu55sCywapSMTHYN
with file https://www.dropbox.com/s/uh0qblvjc4nhxlv/input.txt?dl=0

Comment: By the way your implementation is also not correct, getting same error with your implementation also. Try to run your code here
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/longest-increasing-subsequent

Comment: 'In this challenge you simply have to find the length of the longest **strictly increasing** sub-sequence of the given sequence.'
My snippet is not meant to do this. Please read the problem statement carefully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116306/discussion-between-yash-tewari-and-atinesh).