# How do I memoize this LIS python2.7 algorithm properly?

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

I'm practicing Dynamic Programming and I am writing the Longest Increasing Subsequence problem.

I have the DP solution:

```
def longest_subsequence(lst, lis=[], mem={}):
  if not lst:
    return lis
  if tuple(lst) not in mem.keys():
    if not lis or lst[0] > lis[-1]:
      mem[tuple(lst)] = max([longest_subsequence(lst[1:], lis+[lst[0]], mem), longest_subsequence(lst[1:], lis, mem)], key=len)
    else:
     mem[tuple(lst)] = longest_subsequence(lst[1:], lis, mem)
  return mem[tuple(lst)]
```

And a non-memoized version

```
def longest_subsequence(lst, lis=[]):
  if not lst:
    return lis
  if not lis or lst[0] > lis[-1]:
    result = max([longest_subsequence(lst[1:], lis+[lst[0]]), longest_subsequence(lst[1:], lis)], key=len)
  else:
    result = longest_subsequence(lst[1:], lis)
  return result
```

However, the two functions have different behaviours. For example, the test case `longest_subsequence([10,9,2,5,3,7,101,18])` fails for the memoized version.

```
>>> longest_subsequence([10,9,2,5,3,7,101,18])
[10, 101]
```

The non-memoized version is fully correct however (although much slower).

```
>>> longest_subsequence([10,9,2,5,3,7,101,18])
[2, 5, 7, 101]
```

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I've only given your code a cursory look, but by any chance have you called the memoized version in your interpreter session before? Mutable default arguments retain state. That may be messing you up.

Comment: Nope! both of those results are from fresh sessions @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your state depends on both `lst` and previous item you have picked. But you are only considering the `lst`. That is why you are getting incorrect results. To fix it you just have to add previous item to your dynamic state.

```
def longest_subsequence(lst, prev=None, mem={}):
  if not lst:
    return []
  if (tuple(lst),prev) not in mem:
    if not prev or lst[0] > prev:
      mem[(tuple(lst),prev)] = max([[lst[0]]+longest_subsequence(lst[1:], lst[0]), longest_subsequence(lst[1:], prev)], key=len)
    else:
     mem[(tuple(lst),prev)] = longest_subsequence(lst[1:], prev)

  return mem[(tuple(lst),prev)]

print longest_subsequence([3,5,6,2,5,4,19,5,6,7,12])
```

Note that using the `tuple(list)` as your dynamic state is not a very good idea. You can simply use the index of the item in the `list` that you are checking instead of the whole list:

```
def longest_subsequence(lst, index=0, prev=None, mem={}):
  if index>=len(lst):
    return []
  if (index,prev) not in mem:
    if not prev or lst[index] > prev:
      mem[(index,prev)] = max([[lst[index]]+longest_subsequence(lst, index+1, lst[index]), longest_subsequence(lst, index+1, prev)], key=len)
    else:
      mem[(index,prev)] = longest_subsequence(lst,index+1, prev)

  return mem[(index,prev)]

print longest_subsequence([3,5,6,2,5,4,19,5,6,7,12])
```

For more efficient approaches you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631726/how-to-determine-the-longest-increasing-subsequence-using-dynamic-programming) question.

Comment: oooh i like the index of the list much better, thank you!

Comment: So there is actually a case that breaks this memoized version that I just discovered, please see edit!

Comment: @ylun.ca Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I had just discovered that Tempux's answer did not work for all cases.

I went back and through about encapsulating the entire state into the memoization dictionary  and thus added `tuple(lis)` as part of the key. Also, the `lst` index trick may not be as easy to implement since I am mutating `lst` through the recursion, hence why I am using `tuple()` as my keys.

The reasoning behind what I did is that multiple `lis` may have the same `[-1]` value. So, with this new state, the code is:

```
def longest_subsequence(lst, lis=[],mem={}):
  if not lst:
    return lis
  if (tuple(lst),tuple(lis)) not in mem:
    if not lis or lst[0] > lis[-1]:
      mem[(tuple(lst),tuple(lis))] = max([longest_subsequence(lst[1:], lis+[lst[0]]), longest_subsequence(lst[1:], lis)], key=len)
    else:
     mem[(tuple(lst),tuple(lis))] = longest_subsequence(lst[1:], lis)
  return mem[(tuple(lst),tuple(lis))]
```

This works for all cases I have tested so far.

Comment: I have updated the answer. I should warn you that using `tuple(lst)` and `tuple(lis)` as dynamic states highly increase the complexity of the program.

Comment: awesome, yea i realised this, the memory usage becomes quite high over large inputs. I'll probably try to implement this using indices later on