# Time complexity of an algorithm that runs 1+2+...+n times;

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

To start off I found this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43057723/example-of-123-n-sum-algorithm) that references the time complexity to be O(n^2), but it doesn't answer the question of why O(n^2) is the time complexity but instead asks for an example of such an algorithm. From my understanding an algorithm that runs 1+2+3+...+n times would be
less than O(n^2). For example, take this function

```js
function(n: number) {
    let sum = 0;

    for(let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < i+1; j++) {
            sum += 1;
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Here are some input and return values

| num | sum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 10 |
| 5 | 15 |
| 6 | 21 |
| 7 | 28 |

From this table you can see that this algorithm runs in less than O(n^2) but more than O(n). I also realize than algorithm that runs 1+(1+2)+(1+2+3)+...+(1+2+3+...+n) is true O(n^2) time complexity. For the algorithm stated in the problem, do we just say it runs in O(n^2) because it runs more than O(log n) times?

Comment: Where do you get O(log n) from? That is even less than O(n)... See [Wikipedia on 1+2+3+4+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)

Comment: @trincot The question isn't about how to calculate 1+2+3+4..., that's simple mathematics. The question is about the time complexity of an algorithm that runs n(n-1)/2 times. But I agree about the O(log n), that was a mistake on my part, it was more a comparison and doesn't have a lot of weight with the original question.

Comment: The thing is that we use the same mathematics when it comes to asymptotic complexity. Maybe that was your question?

Comment: 1 + 2 + 3 + ... +n = n*(n+1)/2= (n²+n)/2. O( (n²+n)/2) = O(n²+n) = O(n²)+O(n) = O(n²)

Comment: For the visually inclined, instead of a square, it's a triangle. It's still `n^2` because it's a shape in 2-dimensions _vs_ `n` at infinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's known that 1 + 2 + ... + n has a short form of `n * (n + 1) / 2`. Even if you didn't know that, you have to consider that, when `i` gets to `n`, the inner loop runs **at most** `n` times. So you have exactly `n` times (for outer loop `i`), each running at most `n` times (for inner loop `j`), so the `O(n^2)` becomes more apparent.

I agree that the complexity would be exactly `n^2` if the inner loop also ran from 0 to n, so you have your reasons to think that a loop `i` from 0 to `n` and another loop `j` from 0 to `i` has to perform better and that's true, but with big Oh notation you're actually measuring the degree of algorithm's complexity, not the exact number of operations.

p.s. `O(log n)` is usually achieved when you split the main problem into sub-problems.

Comment: In 1 + 1 + 1 + ... + 1 + n, the inner loop runs at most n times. Even if there are n copies of "1 +", this is still only 2 n = O(n).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think it clears it up a little bit. I think the problem stemmed from my misunderstanding of what Big O notation is actually about. I can see how you get to O(n^2) from the inner loop running "at most" n times.

Comment: @MasonClark - my comment is meant to show how that exact line of reasoning is  wrong even when one iteration actually does run n times.

Comment: @AlexReinking Can the time complexity be O(n) when the algorithm always runs more than n times?

Comment: @MasonClark - Yes. If it always runs 100*n times, it is still O(n)

Comment: @AlexReinking But it doesn't run in O(c*n) because c is not a constant, c grows as n grows

Comment: @AlexReinking it is not `2n`. You have one iteration for inner loop when `i` is 0, you have TWO iterations for inner loop when `i` is 1, you have `n` iterations when `i` is `n - 1`. There are at most `n` copies of `1 + ...`, as you said, but not twice, there are `n` such sequences.

Comment: I downvoted because the statement is too loose and it has caused confusion. The claim is that a loop which runs `n` times and which executes a statement fewer than `n` times in each iteration is `O(n^2)`. This is _technically correct_, but it is very, very loose. The example I gave of a hypothetical loop that executes a statement once on every iteration until the last is `O(n)`, which is asymptotically better than `O(n^2)`.

Comment: I have even explained that OP has reasons to believe that the algorithm presented is a bit faster than having 2 loops each running from 1 to n, but at the end of the day, it is still `O(n^2)`. It's true that the inner loop has fewer steps than `n`, but, on average, it still runs `(n + 1) / 2` times, so inner loop has `O(n)` complexity.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should interpret the table differently. The O(N^2) complexity says that if you double the input N, the runtime should quadruple (take 4 times as long). In this case, the function(n: number) returns a number mirroring its runtime. I use f(N) as a short for it.

So say N goes from 1 to 2, which means the input has doubled (2/1 = 2). The runtime then has gone from f(1) to f(2), which means it has increased f(2)/f(1) = 3/1 = 3 times. That is not 4 times, but the Big-O complexity measure is asymptotic, dealing with the situation where N approaches infinity. If we test another input doubling from the table, we have f(6)/f(3) = 21/6 = 3.5. It is already closer to 4.

Let us now stray outside the table and try more doublings with bigger N. For example we have f(200)/f(100) = 20100/5050 = 3.980  and f(5000)/f(2500) = 12502500/3126250 = 3.999. The trend is clear. As N approaches infinity, a doubled input tends toward a quadrupled runtime. And that is the hallmark of O(N^2).

Comment: I upvoted you, I liked your approach to be honest :) It's worth noting that the ratio indeed approaches `4`. Sum of first `n` numbers is `n * (n + 1) / 2`, which is `(n^2 + n) / 2`. Sum of first `2n` number is `2n * (2n + 1) / 2`, which is `(4n^2 + 2n) / 2`. We have limit when `n` goes to infinity for `(4n^2 + 2n) / (n^2 + n)`. Applying L'Hospital rule, the limit is indeed `4`.

Comment: @Silviu Burcea. Thanks. I appreciate it. The approach I suggest uses benchmarking rather than math to get a grip on the Big-O of some code. Of course, both should be in the toolbox but benchmarking is often good enough for everyday programming. Benchmarking complexity has a black-box feel to it. You study how the code behaves rather than how it looks.