# Finding longest sequence according to requirements (Dynamic Programming)

Tags: sequence, dynamic-programming

''[How to determine the longest increasing subsequence using dynamic programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631726/how-to-determine-the-longest-increasing-subsequence-using-dynamic-programming)'' didn't help me enough that I could do it on my own so I am asking for your help.

I have a sequence of integers: `(-2, 4, 1, 1, 5, -2, 3, 3, -1, 1)`. I want to find longest sequence of them according to these requirements using dynamic programming (`X` here is a number, `i` its index):

1. The numbers have to go in order, their indexes would keep increasing
2. If the index is an odd number, this requirement has to be met: `Xi <= Xi+1`, if the index is an even number, this requirement has to be met: `Xi >= Xi+1`.

For example longest sequence would be: `(-2, 4, 1, 5, -2, 3, -1, 1)`. Any help is greatly appreciated, I have been on this for the whole day..!

Comment: If that in quotes is another question on SO, please link it for other readers, to whom it may be useful. _"I have been on this for the whole day"_ And what code did you come up with so far? SO is not a code-writing service; some evidence of prior effort is usually expected.

Comment: I am trying to think of a way to implement before mentioned code for my needs, but so far unsuccessfully, otherwise I would of posted what I have

Comment: Just how fast do you want the solution to be? An `O(n^2)` solution is rather straightforward, with `fun (index) = max length of sequence ending on this index`. Improving it to `O(n log n)` looks possible, using the same idea as the LIS solution you linked above, but with different requirements for even and odd positions.

Comment: I managed to solved it on my own, thank You for the responses