# Largest smaller value in left subarray for all elements

Tags: sub-array

I was solving the question of [Longest Increasing Sub-sequence](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-increasing-subsequence/) using dynamic programming with `O(n^2)` as per following pseudocode (Basically we are doing bottom-up approach to get length of largest increasing sub-sequence that ends at index `i` for `all i of given array`):

```
#nums is sequence of numbers like [10,9,2,5,3,7,101,18]
dp=[1]*len(nums) #dp[i] is length of longest increasing sub-sequence ending at element nums[i]
for i in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(i):
        if nums[i]>nums[j]:
            dp[i]=max(dp[i], dp[j]+)
#max(dp) will give the length of Longest Increasing Sub-sequence
```

Though I got a different approach for [`O(nlog(n))` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631726/how-to-determine-the-longest-increasing-subsequence-using-dynamic-programming) for above question, I thought of a modification in above approach that led me to another problem and I couldn't think of if I could solve that problem in better than `O(n^2)` time.

I thought that if I could know the largest element smaller than `nums[i]` for `all i in [0, len(nums)-1]` then I could do something like this (I am not sure if this approach is perfectly okay).

```
#nums is sequence of numbers like [10,9,2,5,3,7,101,18]

left=[]
#Suppose left is a list of length len(nums) such that left[i] will give largest element smaller than nums[i] in left sub-array for nums (excluding i)
#i.e. for above nums array, left  = [-1,-1,-1,2,2,5,10,10] #I am showing values here for clarity but I can as well store index of largest element smaller than nums[i] for quick access
#No element is left to 10 so left[0]=-1
#No element left to 9 is smaller than 9 so left[1]=-1
#No element left to 2 is smaller than 2 so left[2]=-1
#In array left to 5, 2 is than largest element smaller than 5 so, left[3]=2, and so on

#Now
dp=[1]*len(lst) #dp[i] is length of longest increasing sub-sequence ending at element nums[i]
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if left[i]!=-1:
        dp[i]=max(dp[i], dp[left[i]]+1) #Assuming I am storing indices in array left
```

**Now**, my question is not if above approach for the above mentioned problem is correct **BUT** that how to make the array `left` in less than `O(n^2)`. If I could get `left` in less than `O(n^2)` the it will be worth to check if above approach works (though that's not the intention of asking this question here, I added that to show how I came across above problem). Can `left` be built in less than `O(n^2)`. For clarity I am adding more input and output below for `left` (In below examples I will be showing required index in `left`):

```
Input: [10,9,2,5,3,7,101,18]
Output: [-1,-1,-1,2,2,3,0,0]

Input: [10,9,8,7,6,8]
Output: [-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,3] #largest element smaller than 8 in left sub-array of 8 is 7 whose index is 3

Input: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
Output: [-1,0,1,2,3,4,5] #no element in left sub-array of element 0, so left[0]=-1
```