# n.Logn algorithm to find longest subsequence not the length

Tags: algorithm, lis

This code finds the length of the longest subsequence in n.logn  time but not the correct sequence.

How to find the sequence that is longest in n.logn not the length?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include <vector>



int longestIncreasingSubsequence(int arr[], int n) {
    std::vector<int> temp;

temp.push_back(arr[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {

    if (arr[i] > temp.back()) {
        temp.push_back(arr[i]);
    } else {

        int ind = lower_bound(temp.begin(), temp.end(), arr[i]) - temp.begin();

        temp[ind] = arr[i];

    }

}
return temp.size();

}

int main() {
// Example usage
int arr[] = {10, 22, 9, 33, 21, 50, 41, 60, 80};
int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

int sequenceSize = longestIncreasingSubsequence(arr, n);


std::cout << "Size of in the Longest Increasing Subsequence: " << sequenceSize;

return 0;
}
```

Longest subsequence numbers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the longest increasing subsequence using dynamic programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631726/how-to-determine-the-longest-increasing-subsequence-using-dynamic-programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add two more informations:

- The index that corresponds with a value in `temp`, i.e. where its value came from in the input `arr`. We can maintain an array `idx` such that if `temp[j]` is `arr[i]`, then `idx[j]` is `i`.
- Given such an index in `arr`, maintain what its *predecessor* was at the moment that value was added/updated in `temp`. We could call that array `prev`.

When you have that, you can reconstruct the values from the sequence. See also the pseudo code presented at [Wikipedia - Longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence#Efficient_algorithms).

Here is your code extended with those arrays (I opted for vectors), and the loop to reconstruct the sequence itself:

```cpp
std::vector<int> longestIncreasingSubsequence2(int arr[], int n) {
    std::vector<int> temp;
    if (n == 0) return temp; 
    // backreferences from index in arr to a previous index in arr
    std::vector<int> prev(n, 0); 
    // index from where the corresponding value in temp was retrieved
    std::vector<int> idx(n, 0);
 
    temp.push_back(arr[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        int ind;
        if (arr[i] > temp.back()) {
            ind = temp.size();
            temp.push_back(arr[i]);
        } else {
            ind = std::lower_bound(temp.begin(), temp.end(), arr[i]) - temp.begin();
            temp[ind] = arr[i];
        }
        idx[ind] = i;
        if (ind) prev[i] = idx[ind - 1];
    }
    // Reconstruct the longest increasing sequence
    int k = idx[temp.size() - 1];
    for (int j = temp.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        temp[j] = arr[k];
        k = prev[k];
    }
    return temp;
}
```